# Typescript compiler complains about index expression not being a number

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have this TypeScript code:

```
namespace MyNamespace {

    // This map can be used to convert a rank to a character
    let rank_to_char_map = ['', '', '2', '3'];

    export class Card {
        private _rank: Number;

        constructor() {
                this._rank = 3;
        }

        toString(): String {
            return rank_to_char_map[this._rank];
        }
    }
}
```

The Visual Studio highlight an error on the code line in the toString function that read "TS2342    An index expression argument must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.". However as you can see this._rank is indeed of type Number.

When I save the file a javascript file is created with the expected result :

```
Card.prototype.toString = function () {
    return rank_to_char_map[this._rank];
};
```

Am I missing something?

(I'm new to TypeScript)

Comment: It's `number`, not `Number`.

Comment: @torazaburo oh, I knew it was gonna be a newb error. Why did Typescript accepted "Number" as a type then?

Comment: `Number` is a perfectly valid type, but it's different from `number`.

Comment: @MathieuPagé Same story for `String`-> `string`